# How to achieve this border button effect? (Photoshop)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient, effects, borders, button

Im trying to replicate this border button effect (the gradients, fill color and shadows; forget about the icon) but I don't know where to start

[image]

Can you give me a way to replicate it straight away or some advices?

Sorry about the quality

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bottom layer has a linear gradient fill, from lighter blue to darker blue.

Top layer is an ellipse shape layer filled orange, with a Stroke Layer Style added. See Layer Style settings blow.

[image]
Click on image to see in more detail

I can't really tell if there are any other details since the image you posted is such poor quality.